# Locate All Emacs Autosaves and Backups in one folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

What do I need to add to my `.emacs` to get it to save all of my autosaves and backups into one directory? I don't do a lot of `.emacs` configuration, and I just can't get the variables out of emacsWiki to play right. Anybody mind sharing how they do it? I would prefer to have the saves placed in `/tmp/emacs/{username}/{autosaves | backups}`

BONUS, configuration to do the same for TRAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [gnu emacs backup files](http://snarfed.org/space/gnu%20emacs%20backup%20files)
**GNU Emacs**

```
;; Put autosave files (ie #foo#) in one place, *not*
;; scattered all over the file system!
(defvar autosave-dir
 (concat "/tmp/emacs_autosaves/" (user-login-name) "/"))

(make-directory autosave-dir t)

(defun auto-save-file-name-p (filename)
  (string-match "^#.*#$" (file-name-nondirectory filename)))

(defun make-auto-save-file-name ()
  (concat autosave-dir
   (if buffer-file-name
      (concat "#" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "#")
    (expand-file-name
     (concat "#%" (buffer-name) "#")))))

;; Put backup files (ie foo~) in one place too. (The backup-directory-alist
;; list contains regexp=>directory mappings; filenames matching a regexp are
;; backed up in the corresponding directory. Emacs will mkdir it if necessary.)
(defvar backup-dir (concat "/tmp/emacs_backups/" (user-login-name) "/"))
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons "." backup-dir)))
```

A version for **XEmacs** can be found if you follow the link at the top of this answer.

Comment: Ah ok, this might be it. Anything for TRAMP mode?

Comment: Too much magic. Only customizing `backup-directory-alist`'s value is needed. Type `M-x customize-variable backup-directory-alist` and set to the preferred "catchall" directory. No need for dotemacs editing.

Answer (score 5):

From [AutoSave on emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave):

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

There is also some info on tweaking the settings with TRAMP in mind as well.